# State machine for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

It seems like there are several state machine gems out there, acts_as_state_machine, state_machine, transitions, workflow, aasm. What's the one that developers use the most?

Answer (score 2):

According to [ruby-toolbox.com](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/state_machines.html) the most popular is [aasm](https://github.com/rubyist/aasm).

**UPD.** Now the most popular is state_machine but you know where to look for it.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have asked this question a long time ago, but have not yet accepted an answer.

Since Rails 3, there is a separate gem for that now. I suggest you read this tiny blog post

http://dev.netizer.pl/transitions-state-machine-for-rails-3.html

Example:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveRecord::Transitions

  # default field name is 'state', 
  # but if you want 'status'
  # you can write "state_machine :status do" instead
  state_machine do 
    state :started # first one is initial state
    state :finished
  end

end
```